# Are global attributes possible in lightning component?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, aura-attribute

It is possible to create attribute as global, I mean that attribute can be get & set in any lightning component or can we set the parent component attributes?

Comment: yes you can use global,private access specifiers in lightning.Please explain a bit briefly if you have any other questions.

Comment: My question is, Is it possible to set the attribute values of outer lightning component from inner lightning component? if yes, then how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution, By using lightning event we can pass values from any component to any component like from outer component to inner component, inner component to outer component and from sibling component too.

**Steps:**

1. Create a lightning event with attributes which you want to pass to
   cmp on particular event.
2. Register the lightning event in the component from where you want to
   pass the values/from where the event is gona happen.
3. Add handler in component in which you are going to access the parameter

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There are couple ways to handle this

**1.Approach 1 involves using a static resource file to store all the global values**

Here is how a code in your static resource look like

```
(function(w){
  "use strict"; //Optional because LC on LockerService active runs in strict mode

  var globalConstants = {
    "variable1":"abc",
    "variable2":"zyz"
  };

  w.globalvalues = globalConstants;

})(window);
```

And then in lightning component you will use like below

```
  ltng:require scripts="{!$Resource.TestScript}" afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.afterScriptsLoaded}" />
   <ui:button label="Do job" press="{!c.populateConstants}"/>
```

The controller

```
populateConstants : function(cmp){
  globalvalues.variable1; 
  globalvalues.variable2; 
}
```

Note you can use this on all init handler to load this data

**2.Use an attribute in Parent component and then trickle down the attribute in all the components like below**

```
<attribute name="constant" type="String" default="Hello"/>
```

The child will have similar attribute and you will call like below

```
<c:childcomponent constant="{!v.constant}"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for response, but by using the first approach, it will be difficult if my global variables/attributes are dynamic, Every time I have to update & access. And the second approach is passing values from outer cmp to inner cmp, it will not work vice versa.

Comment: @shilpa your question said global attributes .Please be specific with questions. Global variables in JS means different than one can imagine if events.

Answer (score 0):

See one answer to [With Summer 18 and LockerService is there any global storage?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/221356/with-summer-18-and-lockerservice-is-there-any-global-storage/221364#221364)
The concept is to pass a global object from each outer container to each inner container.  This "global" object is shared and can be modified by any component that is given the reference.